# Custom tags along with histogram & HttpStatus in micrometer

Tags: java, spring, micrometer, spring-micrometer

How can we get *custom tags* along with  *histogram* and *HttpStatus* in the **micrometer** **Timer**.

We tried **@Timed** but it doesn't allow custom tags.

We tried **Timer.Sample** but then we can't get HTTP status code if we throw an exception before we stop the *timer* in the *finally* block of code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: are these custom metrics or the out of the box "http.server.requests" metrics?

Comment: These were custom tags. We handled it by overriding DefaultWebMvcTagsProvider

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. Could you maybe provide a code sample to help me better understand your problem?